# What is the legality of publishing a free game on itch.io under the age of 18?

Tags: legal, publishing

I am planning on publishing my first game on itch.io and I need to know if this is legal.

The game will be free and I don't plan on receiving any type of monetization on the game if that's important.

Comment: And congratulation for finishing your first game or at least bring it up to the stage where you are ready for publishing

Comment: As long as you don't add a payment method, the only personal information itch.io has about you is your email address. They have no way to find out your actual age. And even if they do, the worst they could do is delist your games.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes. At the time of writing itch.io allows individuals under 18 years to publish games if they have parental or guardian consent. I quote from [itch.io Terms of Service](https://itch.io/docs/legal/terms):

> If you register an account to sell, distribute, or publish games or other content on itch.io, you agree to be bound to the terms of this Agreement as a platform publisher (“Publisher”). Publishers affirm that they are either more than 18 years of age, or possess legal parental or guardian consent, and are fully able and competent to enter into the terms, conditions, obligations, affirmations, representations and warranties set forth in this Agreement.

Comment: In other words, you would actually be allowed to monetise your game on itch.io, so long as you meet the other requirements.